# Datatable pagination not working on select all option

Tags: php, jquery

im using //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js also implemented select all feature but problem is if Im trying to go pagination page say 4 and when i click on select all on same page table redirects to page 1. but actually rows on page 4 selected. i want stay on same pagination where I click on select all. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add option `bStateSave` to your datatables code.

Example:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bStateSave": true
  } );
} );
```

This will save your current state in a cookie and when you return back, it will maintain it.

The examples of state are (sort by column, sort order, search and current page etc...)

More Information:

> Enable or disable state saving. When enabled a cookie will be used to
>   save table display information such as pagination information, display
>   length, filtering and sorting. As such when the end user reloads the
>   page the display will match what they had previously set up.